# Calculating distance between two points with coordinates using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2

I have an attribute table with coordinates of two point, the beginning and the end: (x1, y1)-begin and (x2,y2)-the end.

How can I calculate distance between these coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

The attributes of a single feature have two pairs of coordinates in the one record? If so, then just create a field and use field calculator. Using the VBScript parser it's just this:

```
sqr((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
```

This assumes you are working in a projected coordinate system. Won't work in lat/long.