# QGIS 3x calculate distance between two points with coordinates

Tags: qgis, distance

I have a problem, very similar to [Calculating distance between two points with coordinates using ArcGIS Desktop](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187228/calculate-distance-between-two-points-with-coordinates) where I would like to calculate the distance between two polygons (circles) with their coordinates defined by a centroid function in the field calculator.

I found some possible options to calculate the distance between them:

1. with [Python console](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/323854/distance-between-two-points-on-qgis-3-4-7-and-python-3-7):  where it looks like I should do the calculation point by point
2. [Distance matrix](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_to_calculate_the_distance_between_points_in_Qgis) - not really applicable in y case, as I have the polygons instead of points
3. NNjoin plugin - it looks like some layers must be merged, I don't want that
4. [GRASS v.distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28038/calculating-minimum-distance-between-points-and-polygons-in-qgis) - I used it, but I am getting an error as you see below.

[image]

1. I also used the following formula:

   ```
     distance(($geometry),geometry(get_feature_by_id('Area9_Poles', 1)))
   ```

as per the answer below:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231575/calculate-distance-between-two-points-in-qgis-field-calculator

but it gives me the cumulative distance from one point only.

[image]

So, the distance is calculated always from P1. If you look at the image above you will get my point.
In the Distance [meters] column I need the calculation:
from P1 to P2 distance (which is correct)
from P2 to P3 distance, which is not correct, because it's calculated from P1 to P3 and gives 47m, whereas it is 27.

What is missing in this formula then?

How can I calculate the distance consequently from the last point instead of the very first one?

My full data attribute table is below:

[image]

Comment: Have you had a look at `join by nearest`? It should do, what you're looking for.

Comment: I found sth like this:
geomnearest(Area_9 Area9_Poles)

Comment: Yes indeed. I already attached my data attribute table, you can see. I need the distance calculation from p1 to p2, from p2 to p3 and so on, based on the geometry (XY coordinates). All elements are tagged in the fid order (1st column).

Comment: As per the [Help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) please **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings** in your posts.  An example of a greeting is "Good morning".